# Draw my drawable Image on canvas?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-drawable

How to draw my drawable Image on the canvas? I am getting my image from the Resource and draw that image on the canvas. Is that Possible we can declare multiple canvas and set all in to one ?
I have already image on the canvas and want to draw a drawable image on that?

```
private Bitmap drawtextonimage(Bitmap bitmap, String text, String caption) {
    caption = caption.replace("\n", " ");
```

Declaring Canvas and Paint ?

```
    Canvas cs = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint tPaint = new Paint();
    Paint captionPaint = new Paint();

    if (text.equals("Good")) {
        tPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    } else {
        tPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    tPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    tPaint.setTextSize(30);

    //

    captionPaint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    captionPaint.setAlpha(100);
    captionPaint.setTextSize(25);
    captionPaint.setTextScaleX((float) 0.7);
    captionPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    captionPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);
    captionPaint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0, 1f, Color.WHITE);

    /*Canvas cs1 = new Canvas(bitmap);

        cs1.drawRect(0, bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap.getWidth(), 500, tPaint);

       // canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 77, 60, paint );
        Paint zPaint = new Paint();
         cs1.drawARGB((int) 0.5,54,54,200);*/ 

//         cs.drawText(text, 60, 60, tPaint);
```

This Method get my drawable image and draw on canvas but it is not working?

```
     Resources res = getResources();
     Bitmap bitmapx = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.overlay_good_full);
     Bitmap bitmapxx = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.overlay_bad_full);
    if(text.equals("Good"))
    {


        cs.drawBitmap(bitmapx, 0, 0, new Paint());
        //cs.drawBitmap(bitmapx, 0, 0, tPaint);

    }
    else
    {
         // cs.drawBitmap(bitmapxx, 0, 0, tPaint);

    }

    cs.drawText(caption, (bitmap.getWidth() / 2), bitmap.getHeight()
            , captionPaint);




//  canvas.drawBitmap(image, 0, 0, null);


//  Log.i("Caption", caption);
    return bitmap;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? do you get any exception?And if it doesn't work first you need to check your text.equals("Good") condition whether it works or not.

Comment: TRY cs.setBitMap(bitmapx); instead...

Comment: No it is not showing that drawable image.

Comment: did you tried Canvas cs=new Canvas(bitmapx)..??

Comment: I tried cs.setBitmap(bitmapx); it throws illegal exception.

Comment: something is wrong with your bitmaox..

Comment: jigar Actually I have already an image on the canvas as you can see the Canvas cs = new Canvas(bitmap); I just want to draw another image on that.

Comment: @ridoy condition works i didt get any exception

Comment: try to set width and height of image in drawBitmap method

Comment: you need to set some valid value instead of your 0, 0 inside drawBitmap().

Comment: Yes I tried this I have set 100,100 but it doesnot show that drawable image

Comment: Yes you are right when I put  cs.drawBitmap(bitmapx, 20, 20, new Paint()); it shows on the lower right corner and half image . Now image shows fine but not display the right position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will draw a Drawable from a resource onto a canvas created from a Bitmap (in this case a bitmap from a camera preview). This is tested and works with API 22+ (have not tested it with earlier versions):

```js
            Bitmap cameraBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length, opt);
            Canvas camImgCanvas = new Canvas(cameraBitmap);
            Drawable d = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.myDrawable);
            //Centre the drawing
            int bitMapWidthCenter = cameraBitmap.getWidth()/2;
            int bitMapheightCenter = cameraBitmap.getHeight()/2;
            d.setBounds(bitMapWidthCenter, bitMapheightCenter, bitMapWidthCenter+d.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    bitMapheightCenter+d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            //And draw it...
            d.draw(camImgCanvas);
```

Comment: @LiNKeR - this is the same approach - is that what you are highlighting?. The only difference here is the canvas is being created from a bitmap from the camera preview and the bounds are being calculated programatically.